# Rails prevent HAML from escaping a link (w/ helper haml_tag)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I'm trying to create a simple menu and I came across this problem: HAML keeps escaping my links to html entities. I have a helper that is supposed to generate a menu:

```
def buildMainMenu(file=Rails.root.join("config","menu.yaml"))
    ... some operations ...

    link = url_for par.merge({:controller=>mitem["controller"], :action=>mitem["action"]})

    ... some more operations yay ...

    haml_tag :a, mitem["label"], :href=>link 
end
```

par is `{"testPARAM1"=>"testVAL1","testPARAM2"=>"testVAL2"}`

Sadly the output is

`<a href='/test/test1?testPARAM1=testVAL1&amp;testPARAM2=testVAL2'>Test2</a>`

I've looked for a while now and I can't seem to find how to force HAML to **NOT** escape my strings :(

Comment: where is this function, in a helper or somewhere else?

Comment: @DavidLesches: yes this function is in the main application helper (`/app/helpers/application_helper.rb`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out (I wish I've found it before spending over an hour on it but hey).
For anyone interested:

There are two functions `html_safe` and `raw` that do the trick. Used as follow:

- haml_tag :a, mitem["label"], :href=>link.html_safe
- haml_tag :a, mitem["label"], :href=>raw(link)

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't 100% what you are looking for, but personally I would refactor this - this is going to cause you headaches and anyway, rendering html within a helper isn't ideal at all.

I'd change the helper function to get your YAML file, or whatever is going on there, and output a final array with the correct items.

Make a _header.html.haml partial (put it in a directory 'shared'), the partial will call the helper function, get the array, and since you are in a view you can loop with normal techniques, and use link_to, etc, and all your problems are solved.

This is a much cleaner way of doing things.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. This was indeed my initial approach, but I got stuck when it came to one thing: recursion. My code relies on recursion (w/ lambda function inside my `buildMainMenu`, as items can have sub menu's).

Comment: OK. I'm not recommending this as a clean idea, but as you've already tried the other way - in your helper file I think you can do an "include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper" and then use link_to

Comment: I have taken your approach but the problem persists - HAML keeps filtering my strings and escaping them.